# Expand ini settings for zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, ini

I'm having the following ini setting file, named networks.ini:

```
[networks1]
networks[] = 'Twitter'
networks[] = 'Facebook'
networks[] = 'Google'

[networks2 : networks1]
networks[] = 'LinkedIn'
```

Is there a way to get the array to include for networks2 both the networks1 and networks2 values in the same array?
When i try

```
$cfgNetworks = new Zend_Config_Ini(PATH_TO_INI .'networks.ini', 'networks2');
print_r($cfgNetworks->networks->toArray());
```

it returns the LinkedIn network name only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think You can merge arrays this way.
But you can try to explicitly add array keys

```
[networks1]
networks.twitter = 'Twitter'
networks.facebook = 'Facebook'
networks.google = 'Google'

[networks2 : networks1]
networks.linkedin = 'LinkedIn'
```